# Sorting strings with integers and text in Python

Tags: python, string, alphanumeric

I'm making a stupid little game that saves your score in a highscores.txt file.

My problem is sorting the lines.  Here's what I have so far.

Maybe an alphanumeric sorter for python would help?  Thanks.

```
import os.path
import string

def main():
    #Check if the file exists
    file_exists = os.path.exists("highscores.txt")

    score = 500
    name = "Nicholas"

    #If the file doesn't exist, create one with the high scores format.
    if file_exists == False:
        f = open("highscores.txt", "w")
        f.write('Guppies High Scores\n1000..........Name\n750..........Name\n600..........Name\n450..........Name\n300..........Name')

    new_score = str(score) + ".........." + name

    f = open("highscores.txt", "r+")
    words = f.readlines()
    print words

main()
```

Answer (score 4):

after `words = f.readlines()`, try something like:

```
headers = words.pop(0)

def myway(aline):
  i = 0
  while aline[i].isdigit():
    i += 1
  score = int(aline[:i])
  return score

words.sort(key=myway, reverse=True)

words.insert(0, headers)
```

The key (;-) idea is to make a function that returns the "sorting key" from each item (here, a line).  I'm trying to write it in the simplest possible way: see how many leading digits there are, then turn them all into an int, and return that.

Comment: Thanks Alex!  But when I insert that in my code, I'm getting an error:
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xc2' in file read.py on line 24, but no encoding declared; see http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html for details
Any ideas what that's from? Thanks again!

Comment: @Nicholas, there's no non-ASCII text (and in particular no `0xc2` -- in Latin-1, that would be an uppercase-A with a circumflex) in the code I posted, and so of course I have absolutely no idea how you managed to get one into _your_ code.  If you can't spot it in your own code (?!), maybe post that code in a question -- but this really has zero to do with _this_ question, which I appear to have answered satisfactorily, so I suggest you make it a _separate_ question.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to encourage you to store your high scores in a more robust format.  In particular I suggest JSON.

```
import simplejson as json  # Python 2.x
# import json  # Python 3.x

d = {}
d["version"] = 1
d["highscores"] = [[100, "Steve"], [200, "Ken"], [400, "Denise"]]
s = json.dumps(d)
print s
# prints:
# {"version": 1, "highscores": [[100, "Steve"], [200, "Ken"], [400, "Denise"]]}


d2 = json.loads(s)
for score, name in sorted(d2["highscores"], reverse=True):
    print "%5d\t%s" % (score, name)

# prints:
#  400  Denise
#  200  Ken
#  100  Steve
```

Using JSON will keep you from having to write your own parser to recover data from saved files such as high score tables.  You can just tuck everything into a dictionary and trivially get it all back.

Note that I tucked in a version number, the version number of your high score save format.  If you ever change the save format of your data, having a version number in there will be a very good thing.

Comment: +1: or yaml, if you would like it to be more human readable (and do not need to send over the wire)

Comment: Or you could be traditional and use the Python `pickle` module.  That can save any Python data type, and it's included in every Python install.  Not very human-readable though.

Answer (score 0):

Doing a simple string sort on your

```
new_score = str(score) + ".........." + name
```

items isn't going to work since, for example str(1000) < str(500).  In other words, 1000 will come before 500 in an alphanumeric sort.

Alex's answer is good in that it demonstrates the use of a sort key function, but here is another solution which is a bit simpler and has the added advantage of visuallaly aligning the high score displays.

What you need to do is right align your numbers in a fixed field of the maximum size of the scores, thus (assuming 5 digits max and ver < 3.0):

```
new_score = "%5d........%s" % (score, name)
```

or for Python ver 3.x:

```
new_score = "{0:5d}........{1}".format(score, name)
```

For each new_score append it to the words list (you could use a better name here) and sort it reversed before printing.  Or you could use the bisect.insort library function rather than doing a list.append.

Also, a more Pythonic form than

```
if file_exists == False:
```

is:

```
if not file_exists:
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess something went wrong when you pasted from Alex's answer, so here is your code with a sort in there

```
import os.path

def main():
    #Check if the file exists
    file_exists = os.path.exists("highscores.txt")

    score = 500
    name = "Nicholas"

    #If the file doesn't exist, create one with the high scores format.
    if file_exists == False:
        f = open("highscores.txt", "w")
        f.write('Guppies High Scores\n1000..........Name\n750..........Name\n600..........Name\n450..........Name\n300..........Name')

    new_score = str(score) + ".........." + name +"\n"

    f = open("highscores.txt", "r+")
    words = f.readlines()

    headers = words.pop(0)

    def anotherway(aline):
      score="" 
      for c in aline:
          if c.isdigit():
              score+=c
          else:
              break
      return int(score)

    words.append(new_score)
    words.sort(key=anotherway, reverse=True)

    words.insert(0, headers)

    print "".join(words)

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is probably what's generally known as a "Natural Sort". Searching for "natural sort python" gives many results, but there's some good discussion on [ASPN](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/285264/).